# assignment of array pointer in a class

Tags: c++, arrays

```
void SetString(char s1[], char s2[]){
    str1= s1[]; 
    str2= s2[];

}
private: 
    char str1[20];
    char str2[20];
```

What's wrong in that code please some one tell me.

Its giving me following error:

> stringhandler.cpp: In member function ‘void
>   StringHandler::SetString(char*, char*)’:
>
> stringhandler.cpp:25: error: expected primary-expression before ‘]’
>   token stringhandler.cpp:26: error: expected primary-expression before
>   ‘]’ token

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/enZXQ.png)
[image]

Comment: `str1= s1[]; ` That's not valid syntax, what are you trying to do?

Comment: im just trying to pass two string and assigning it to the class fields

Comment: @MaheshDhokade Actually use [strings](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) then, that will make your life way easier.

Answer (score 4):

You can not do `str1=s1[]`. It is not valid. Use this instead to copy an array to another:

```
void SetString(char s1[], char s2[]){
    std::copy(s1, s1+20, std::begin(str1));
    std::copy(s2, s2+20, std::begin(str2));
}
```

---

Even better, use `std::array` instead (if your case is general) or `std::string` if you are dealing with strings as array of char. Something like this:

```
void SetString(const std::array<char,20>& s1, const std::array<char,20>& s2){
    str1=s1;
    str2=s2;
}
private: 
    std::array<char,20> str1;
    std::array<char,20> str2;
```

---

or:

```
void SetString(const std::string& s1, const string& s2){
    str1=s1;
    str2=s2;
}
private: 
    std::string str1;
    std::string str2;
```

Comment: Passing through `const &` is usually pessimistic nowadays. Especially if you're already going to copy them.

Comment: @M.M Thanks for notifying

Answer (score 4):

You can't copy C-strings like that, `s1` and `s2` both decay to a pointer and you have to use `strcpy` to copy them:

```
strcpy(str1, s1);
strcpy(str2, s2);
```

But you're working with C++ so really you should be using `std::string`:

```
void SetString(const std::string& s1, const std::string& s2)
    {
        str1= s1; 
        str2= s2;

    }
private: 
    std::string str1;
    std::string str2;
```

or, for C++11 and higher:

```
void SetString(std::string s1, std::string s2)
    {
        str1= std::move(s1); 
        str2= std::move(s2);

    }
```

This solves a lot of problems that come with C-strings for you.

Comment: `s1` and `s2` should be passed by `const &` here or overloaded for lvalue and rvalue references.

Comment: Or, `str1 = std::move(s1)` and so on.

Comment: @juanchopanza There's a chance OP doesn't have access to C+11, I didn't want to risk getting a compilation error if that's the case.

Comment: OK, then it isn't clear what you gain from passing by value. Maybe you break even for rvalues, but lose out for lvalues.

Comment: im just doing in the program for string operation without using string functions for that im accepting strings from user in main and trying to assign to the class field as u can see i have declared the class fields as private so i can't access it in main function so please simply guide me how to assign the user entered string to the private fields